# As_labeller with expression() in ggplot2 facet_wrap

Tags: r, ggplot2

In

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape)
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(runif(9),3,3))
df$factor <- letters[1:3]
df.m <- melt(df)
ggplot(df.m, aes(variable, value)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  facet_wrap(~factor)
```

i want to change the facet names. According to the ggplot2 tutorials, this is working:

```
new.lab <- as_labeller(c(a="A",b="B",c="C"))
ggplot(df.m, aes(variable, value)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  facet_wrap(~factor, labeller=new.lab)
```

However, this is not:

```
new.lab <- as_labeller(c(a="A",b="B",c=expression(italic("C"))))
ggplot(df.m, aes(variable, value)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  facet_wrap(~factor, labeller=new.lab)
```

How can i get italics (or any other special symbol) in ggplot2 2.0 facets?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

How about `label_parsed` instead?

```
df.m$f2 <- factor(df.m$factor, labels = c("AAA", "bold(BBB)", "italic(CCC)"))
ggplot(df.m, aes(variable, value)) + 
  geom_boxplot() + 
  facet_wrap(~f2, labeller = label_parsed) + 
  theme(text = element_text(size = 20))
```

[image]

Answer (score 10):

You can specify the type of `labeller` here using `label_parsed`,

```
new.lab <- as_labeller(c(a="A", b="B", c="italic(C)"), label_parsed)
ggplot(df.m, aes(variable, value)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  facet_wrap(~factor, labeller = new.lab)
```

Comment: This doesnt seem to work with spaces: Error in parse(text = as.character(values)) : 
  <text>:1:6: unexpected symbol
1: Soil Moisture

Comment: Thx. i got thinks like Clay="Clay~('%')" and MicrobialN="paste(N[mic])" to work out, but how about this: R.minor="italic(Rhinantus~minor)", which is ignored. Rhinantus Minor should appear in italics and separated by a space