# as_labeller with an expression in ggplot2 and facet_wrap

Tags: r, ggplot2

There is an example provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35524202/as-labeller-with-expression-in-ggplot2-facet-wrap), but I just can't make it work. Here is my use case:

```
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(runif(9),8,8))
angles <- c(0.112, 2.633, 3.766, 5.687, 0.867, 7.978, 8.937, 4.652)
df$factor <- as.factor(angles)
df.m <- melt(df)
ggplot(df.m, aes(variable, value)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  facet_wrap(~factor)
```

[image]

Now I want to display rounded angles with the degree symbol. So I tried this

```
new.labs <- as_labeller(paste(round(as.numeric(angles)), "degree"), label_parsed)
ggplot(df.m, aes(variable, value)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  facet_wrap(~factor, labeller=new.labs)
```

But it produces empty strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe `as.labeller` is expecting either a function or a look-up table, not a variable name.

```
new.labs <- as_labeller(function(string) paste(round(as.numeric(string)), "*degree"), label_parsed)

ggplot(df.m, aes(variable, value)) +
    geom_boxplot() +
    facet_wrap(~factor, labeller = new.labs)
```

[image]

Comment: There seem to be a problem with your output, though: it uses the index of the angles, not their values.

Comment: @Ben This looks like angles rounded to me...  How many digits do you want rounded to?  I just rounded to the same amount you did in your question.

Comment: Yes it is... I guess it's week-end time for me :)

Answer (score 1):

Not using as.labeller, but this is simpler:

```
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(runif(9),8,8))
angles <- c(0.112, 2.633, 3.766, 5.687, 0.867, 7.978, 8.937, 4.652)
df$factor <- as.factor(round(angles))
df.m <- melt(df)

ggplot(df.m, aes(variable, value)) +
    geom_boxplot() +
    facet_wrap(~factor, labeller = label_bquote(.(as.character(factor))*degree))
```