# Two separate y-axis titles for two facets of a plot while keeping the facet top strip labels using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-grid

I have this data frame:

```
> str(DF)
'data.frame':   14084 obs. of  6 variables:
.
.
.
 $ Variables: chr  "Height" "Height" "Height" "Height" ...
 $ Values   : num  245 129 301 162 123 125 115 47 46 135 ...
 $ Year     : Factor w/ 2 levels "2015","2016": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
```

I wrapped the plot in two facets (in two columns) using `facet_wrap()` with free axes scales.

```
ggplot(data = DF, aes(x = Year, y = Values)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  facet_wrap("Variables", scales = "free")
```

My problem is:
Both the facets share a common y-axis title. **What I would like, however, is two separate y-axis titles for the two facets.** A common x-axis title is fine for me.

I came across this question   [Showing different axis labels using ggplot2 with facet_wrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37573155/showing-different-axis-labels-using-ggplot2-with-facet-wrap/37574221) 
but it does not solve the problem the way I want as I do not want to lose the facet labels on top. Moreover, my facets are arranged horizontally.

I tried using `labs()`:

```
. . . +
labs(y=c("A", "B"))
```

But it just changes the y-axis title of first facet to `A` and the second facet remains as it is.

How could I address this problem?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not sure if I fully understood what you need, but here is my attempt based on [your suggested link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37574221/5193830) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12660057/5193830).

```
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)
library(gtable)

# Some fake data
set.seed(2018)
df <- data.frame(variables = rep(c("var1", "var2"), times = 100),
                 values = rnorm(100),
                 year = as.factor(2001:2010))

# Make a plot with positioning the strip labels to the right of each facet,
# acting as OY axis titles.
# We will add the top strip labels in the next step,
# using the `grid` & `gtable` packages functionality.
p <- ggplot(df, aes(x = year, y = values, group = year) ) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  facet_wrap(~ variables, scales = "free_y", nrow = 1, 
             strip.position = "left", 
             labeller = as_labeller(c(var1 = "Example var1", 
                                      var2 = "Example var2") ) )  +
  ylab(NULL) +
  theme(strip.background = element_blank(),
        strip.placement = "outside",
        # Customize theme so that is black & white style as requested
        panel.background = element_rect(fill = NA, colour = 'black'),
        panel.grid = element_blank())
p
```

[image]

Add the top strip labels using the functionality of the `grid` & `gtable` packages:

```
# Get gtable object
g <- ggplotGrob(p)
# Sometimes helpful to get an idea about the grobs' position
grid.show.layout(gtable:::gtable_layout(g)) 

# Add an extra top row (make some space)
g <- gtable_add_rows(x = g, heights = unit(0.65, 'cm'), pos = 2)
# First strip
g <- gtable_add_grob(x = g,
                     grobs = list(rectGrob(gp = gpar(col = NA, 
                                                     fill = NA)),
                                  textGrob(label = "var1", 
                                           gp = gpar(col = "black"))),
                     t = 3, l = 7, b = 3, r = 7, 
                     name = c("strip-top-1-rectg", "strip-top-1-text"))
# Second strip
g <- gtable_add_grob(x = g,
                     grobs = list(rectGrob(gp = gpar(col = NA, 
                                                     fill = NA)),
                                  textGrob(label = "var2", 
                                           gp = gpar(col = "black"))),
                     t = 3, l = 13, b = 3, r = 13, 
                     name = c("strip-top-2-rectg", "strip-top-2-text")) 

# Draw the edited plot
grid.newpage()
grid.draw(g)
```

[image]

Comment: You got it right. Thank you. I have done it the way I wanted. Just one thing more, How do I make the plot all black & white including the labels and axes titles? I know the theme() function of ggplot() but here you have used some other functions which I am not familiar with.

Comment: Hi @Muneer. Would have been nice to mention this in your question. I updated my answer. The idea is to just use the `theme` options as you suggested when creating `p` and will trickle down to `g` as well. `ggplot2` is based on `grid`, so will work out just fine. An extra step was to set the strip background to `NA`.

Comment: Everything works fine. Thank you so much for your time.