# Use different scale tick mark labelling functions with facet_wrap() in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet

My question is *similar* to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37573155/showing-different-axis-labels-using-ggplot2-with-facet-wrap) but differs in an important aspect. I want to use different labelling functions created with the `{scales}` package for the *tick mark* labels (not the axis labels). Here's a reproducible example:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

mill <- number_format(scale = 1/1000000, suffix = " M")
thou <- number_format(scale = 1/1000, suffix = " k")

df <- data.frame(cond = rep(c("A", "B", "C"), each = 5),
           x_unit = rep(1:5, 3),
           y_unit = round(c(rnorm(5, 5e6, 10000),
                      rnorm(5, 5e6, 10000),
                      rnorm(5, 5000, 1000))))

ggplot(df, aes(x = x_unit, y = y_unit)) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = mill) +
  facet_wrap(~ cond, scales = "free_y")
```

[image: Example Output]

You might already see where I'm going with this: For facet C, I want to use the labelling function `thou` and not `mill`. How would I do that? I'm pretty sure that the solution with the `labeller` argument in `facet_wrap()` from the question I linked above does not apply here, right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might be interested in `ggh4x::scale_y_facet()`. You give it a way to find the appropriate panel `cond == "C"` and give it a different label function than the default scale. It only works with facets where scales are free. Disclaimer: I'm the author of ggh4x.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

mill <- number_format(scale = 1/1000000, suffix = " M")
thou <- number_format(scale = 1/1000, suffix = " k")

df <- data.frame(cond = rep(c("A", "B", "C"), each = 5),
                 x_unit = rep(1:5, 3),
                 y_unit = round(c(rnorm(5, 5e6, 10000),
                                  rnorm(5, 5e6, 10000),
                                  rnorm(5, 5000, 1000))))

ggplot(df, aes(x = x_unit, y = y_unit)) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = mill) +
  facet_wrap(~ cond, scales = "free_y") +
  ggh4x::scale_y_facet(cond == "C", labels = thou)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-11-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: That is so great and it works, thanks for your answer and especially for your work on the package!

Answer (score 1):

If you're happy with the suffixes being selected automatically, you can use the `cut_long_scale()` helper function available alongside the `scale_cut` option. The advantage over the manually defined scales is that you do not have to know in advance what magnitude the different number ranges will be.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

df <- data.frame(cond = rep(c("A", "B", "C"), each = 5),
                 x_unit = rep(1:5, 3),
                 y_unit = round(c(rnorm(5, 5e6, 10000),
                                  rnorm(5, 5e6, 10000),
                                  rnorm(5, 5000, 1000))))

ggplot(df, aes(x = x_unit, y = y_unit)) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = number_format(scale_cut = cut_long_scale())) +
  facet_wrap(~ cond, scales = "free_y")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-11-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>